# YouTube is much more stable on Edge than Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, microsoft-edge

YouTube is acting weird on Chrome. It will sometimes work perfectly for a while and sometimes the videos will fail to play in even 360p. Whenever that happens, I switch to Edge. 2 identical videos - Chrome tries to keep up to 360p while Edge is rocking 1080p60fps with no problem. I thought it might be AdBlockPlus, as some have stated, but disabling it makes no difference. 2 other extensions are Web Scraper and Dark Mode. Could it be some kind of Proxy/Bug/Unplanned Feature I don't know about?

I'd use Edge all the time, but there are some minor UI issues which I don't experience in Chrome. Don't recommend me browsers, please.

Comment: May be there is some configuration settings in Chrome. You can change video quality in YouTube.

Comment: Have you tried 1/ Reinstalling Chrome? 2/ Disabling Chrome extensions? 3/ Using a new Chrome profile?